# Change Domain VirtualHost paths in Plesk (Apache)

Tags: apache, zend-framework, plesk

I have a domain that'll be using Zend Framework and I need to modify the documentroot for this particular domain to resolve to Zend's path.

Anyone know how to update the virtualhost on a particular domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you don't have to modify the document root.

Put your application files one level above your document root, and put the contents of the zend `public` folder in whatever your document root is (e.g. public_html or htdocs).